# How To Use The <- Operator

Tags: f#

```
     let mutable steve = 1348; 
     let steve <- 202;
printfn "%d" steve;
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

I cannot simply get the num. 202 to print out in the Console. What am I dpoing wrong anyway?

Comment: For next time: it is a good idea to show the error message you get.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the 2nd "let", nor the semicolons.

```
let mutable steve = 1348
steve <- 202
printfn "%d" steve
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```